# Camera randomly freezes after the first frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, avcapturesession

I'm opening the camera in an overlay view to scan QR codes. It normally works fine, but once every 15-20 times or so, the camera freezes immediately after the first frame. The app still runs, and if you press our back button and return to the camera again it will usually not freeze a second time. It happens both on an iPhone 4 with iOS 7.1, and on an iPhone 5s with iOS 8.3, which are the only phones I've access to test it on. As far as I can tell the freeze is completely random. The camera does not run the `captureOutput` delegate function when it's frozen if I aim it at a QR-code, so it seems like it's not just the preview that freezes.

I can't even figure out how to tell programmatically if it froze or not. Running an `NSTimer` with a function logging `self.captureSession.isRunning` always outputs true even after it freezes.

Here's the code I'm using. I've removed unrelated code, but there are some views on top of the camera preview view. I can add them back in if you think they'd be relevant.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [ super viewDidLoad ];

    // Camera / QR-Scanner
    NSError *error;
    self.captureSession = nil;
    self.cameraView = [ [ UIView alloc ] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds ];
    self.cameraView.backgroundColor = [ UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.5f ];

    AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = [ AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo ];
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [ AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:captureDevice error:&error ];
    if ( input ) {
        if ( [ captureDevice isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus ] && [ captureDevice isFocusPointOfInterestSupported ] ) {
            if ( [ captureDevice lockForConfiguration:&error ] ) {
                [ captureDevice setFocusPointOfInterest:CGPointMake( 0.5f, 0.5f ) ];
                [ captureDevice setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus ];
                [ captureDevice unlockForConfiguration ];
            }
        }
        self.captureSession = [ [ AVCaptureSession alloc ] init ];
        [ self.captureSession addInput:input ];
        [ self.captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset352x288 ];

        AVCaptureMetadataOutput *captureMetadataOutput = [ [ AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc ] init ];
        [ self.captureSession addOutput:captureMetadataOutput ];

        dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create( "cqQRScanner", NULL );
        [ captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatchQueue ];
        [ captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectTypes:[ NSArray arrayWithObject:AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode ] ];

        self.videoPreviewLayer = [ [ AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc ] initWithSession:self.captureSession ];
        [ self.videoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill ];

        [ self.captureSession startRunning ];
        /* Also tried this:
        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if ( ![ self.captureSession isRunning ] ) {
                [ self.captureSession startRunning ];
            }
        } );
        */

    } else {
        CLS_LOG( @"%@", [ error localizedDescription ] );
    }
}
```

I've also added these:

```
[ [ NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter ] addObserver:self selector:@selector( didStop ) name:@"AVCaptureSessionDidStopRunningNotification" object:nil ];
[ [ NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter ] addObserver:self selector:@selector( didStart ) name:@"AVCaptureSessionDidStartRunningNotification" object:nil ];
[ [ NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter ] addObserver:self selector:@selector( didRuntimeError ) name:@"AVCaptureSessionRuntimeErrorNotification" object:nil ];
```

coupled with these (CLS_LOG is NSLog through Crashlytics):

```
- ( void ) didStop {
    CLS_LOG( @"Camera did stop" );
}
- ( void ) didStart {
    CLS_LOG( @"Camera did start" );
}
- ( void ) didRuntimeError {
    CLS_LOG( @"Camera did runtime error!" );
}
```

but it doesn't send the runtime error when it freezes either.

Do you have any ideas? Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**
After finishing up the post, I noticed the camera had unfrozen. It took a good 10-15 minutes for it to do so, and I'm now re-testing it on the iPhone 5s. Could it be that it doesn't actually stop, just pauses for a really long time? The rest of the app still runs fine.

Update 2: It seems like going to the home screen and back into the app sometimes unlocks the camera again.

Comment: In Apple's AVCamManual sample code, all communication with the capture session is on a background thread. Multi threading can be tricky but I wonder if it is needed here.

Comment: I don't have much multi threading experience, but looking at that example, do you think I should try to start the captureSession using something along the lines of this from line 214 in their code?
dispatch_async([self sessionQueue], ^{
  [self addObservers];
  
  [[self session] startRunning];
 });

Comment: Looking a bit further into it, I'll try pretty much wrapping the whole thing in a new dispatch_async